# Xamarin.iOS how do I change the status status bar color when there is no Navigation bar

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

When using using a NavigationBar I could write

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = Constants.PrimaryColor;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
```

But I want something like this only a particular ViewController which has no NavigationBar.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
        var attr = new UIStringAttributes();
        attr.ForegroundColor = UIColor.White;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = attr;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
        NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
```

The last line will do the trick...